# Let $G$ be a group. $|G|=21$ and $|Z(G)| \neq 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|Z(G)| = $?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. $|G|=21$ and $|Z(G)| \neq 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|Z(G)| = $ ?

We know that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$. 
By Lagrange's Theorem $|Z(G)|$ divides $|G|$ 
$\Rightarrow |Z(G)| = 3,7,21$

What else do we have to do here to show that $|Z(G)| = 21$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Lemma**: Let $G$ be a group, and denote $Z(G)$ its center. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Going back to the problem we have that $G/Z(G)=1 ~\text{or} ~3 ~\text{or}~ 7$. In each case since the order of $G/Z(G)$ is prime, we can conclude that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. By the Lemma $G$ is abelian hence $Z(G)=G$.

**Proof of the Lemma:** Suppose that $G/Z(G)= <a>$ for some $a\in G$. Then, take $c,d \in G$.

From the hypothesis we have,
$c=a^{k_1} z_1$ and $d=a^{k_2}z_2$ where $z_i\in Z(G)$ and $k_i\in \mathbb{N}$. So,

\begin{align}
cd&=a^{k_1}z_1 a^{k_2} z_2 \\
&=a^{k_1}a^{k_2}z_1  z_2\\
&=a^{k_2}a^{k_1}z_2  z_1\\
&=a^{k_2}z_2a^{k_1}  z_1\\
&=dc
\end{align}

Comment: How do you conclude /()=1 or 3 or 7?

Comment: @user2965071 It is from Lagrange's theorem(https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_Theorem_(Group_Theory)  ) that says $|G|  = |  G/Z(G)||Z(G)|$, and since $|Z(G)|$ is not $1$, the only other possibilities for $|G/Z(G)|$ are the ones suggested.

Comment: @user2965071 By that I meant that the order of $G/Z(G)$ is either 1 or 3 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

$|Z(G)|=21$ iff the group is abelian.

Note that $21=7\cdot3$; can you prove from here that every group of this order has to be abelian (Sylow theorem).

Comment: But what does the group being Abelian have to do with figuring out what the order is? I know the order could be 3, 7, or 21. But the answer in the book says its 21 without justification.

Comment: What's the center of an abelian group?

Comment: The center of an Abelian group is the whole group correct? Since a the center is defined to be elements of a group that commute with every other element, since its Abelian every element commutes with every element. But I still don't see the idea here/

Comment: This answer is wrong, not all groups of order $21$ are abelian.

Comment: This answer is wrong as verret pointed out. So @user2965071, please untick this answer and tick clark's as the right one.

Comment: No, sure. But here we are supposing to have a nontrivial center